# ANGULAR + PRIMENG + STORYBOOK: Error on NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken app.config

Tags: angular, primeng, storybook

I started a new angular APP:

```
ng new my-app
```

Then I added PrimeNG:

```
npm install primeng
```

Finally, I added StoryBook:

```
npx storybook@latest init
```

I created the a new component:

```
ng g c header
```

The component:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  public user: User;
  public projects: Project[] = [];
  public mainProject: Project | undefined;
  public items: MenuItem[] = [];
  public loading: boolean = true;

  @ViewChild(Menu)
  public menu: Menu;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

And created a story for it:

```
const meta: Meta<HeaderComponent> = {
    title: 'HeaderComponent',
    component: HeaderComponent,
    decorators: [
        moduleMetadata({
            imports: [
                DropdownModule,
                ProgressSpinnerModule,
                AvatarModule,
                MenuModule,
                ButtonModule,
                FormsModule,
                BrowserAnimationsModule
            ],
            providers: [{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {} }]
        }),
    ],
};

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<HeaderComponent>;

export const Primary: Story = {
    args: {
        loading: true,
        projects: [{ name: "Project 1", main: true }, { name: "Project 2", main: false }],
        user: { username: "User Default", avatar: "data:image/png;base64...." },
        items: [{ label: "Perfil", icon: "pi pi-fw pi-user" }, { label: "Configurações", icon: "pi pi-fw pi-cog" }]
    },
};
```

And works fine! However, when I add a service in the component:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProjectService {

  constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config: AppConfig, private http: HttpClient) { }

  public list(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.http.get<Project[]>(`${this.config.api.url}/projects`);
  }
}
```

And changed the story to:

```
const meta: Meta<HeaderComponent> = {
    title: 'HeaderComponent',
    component: HeaderComponent,
    decorators: [
        moduleMetadata({
            imports: [
                DropdownModule,
                ProgressSpinnerModule,
                AvatarModule,
                MenuModule,
                ButtonModule,
                FormsModule,
                BrowserAnimationsModule
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {} },
                { provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: { api: { url: "http://localhost:8500/api" } } }
            ]
        }),
    ],
};

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<HeaderComponent>;

export const Primary: Story = {
    args: {
        loading: true,
        projects: [{ name: "Project 1", main: true }, { name: "Project 2", main: false }],
        user: { username: "User Default", avatar: "data:image/png;base64...." },
        items: [{ label: "Perfil", icon: "pi pi-fw pi-user" }, { label: "Configurações", icon: "pi pi-fw pi-cog" }]
    },
};
```

I am getting this error:

> R3InjectorError(Standalone[StorybookWrapperComponent])[ProjectService -> ProjectService -> InjectionToken app.config -> InjectionToken app.config]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken app.config!

In the angular app works fine, no errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After talking with MarkB in StoryBook Discord Channel, I gotta the answer:

```
const meta: Meta<HeaderComponent> = {
    title: 'HeaderComponent',
    component: HeaderComponent,
    decorators: [
        applicationConfig({
            providers: [
                { provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: { api: { url: 'http://localhost:8500/api' } }, },
                { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {} },
                importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule)
            ],
        }),
        moduleMetadata({
            imports: [
                DropdownModule,
                ProgressSpinnerModule,
                AvatarModule,
                MenuModule,
                ButtonModule,
                FormsModule,
                BrowserAnimationsModule,
            ],
        }),
    ],
};

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<HeaderComponent>;

export const Primary: Story = {
    args: {
        loading: true,
        projects: [{ name: "Project 1", main: true }, { name: "Project 2", main: false }],
        user: { username: "User Default", avatar: "data:image/png;base64...." },
        items: [{ label: "Perfil", icon: "pi pi-fw pi-user" }, { label: "Configurações", icon: "pi pi-fw pi-cog" }]
    },
};
```